# How would you prove that this is a group isomorphism?

Tags: group-theory

Let $$M_{a} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & a & \frac{a^2}{2} \\ 0  & 1 & a \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
where $a \in \mathbb{R}$
and let the function $\phi : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow G$ where $\phi(a) = M_a$ and $G$ is the set containing $M_a$.

I've shown this is a group homomorphism under addition in $\mathbb{R}$ and multiplication in $G$, but how would I show it's an isomorphism, if it is?

I think it is... mainly from imagining in my head that if I specify any value of $a$ and fix it to be say $x$,
then $M_x$ must bring back the value of $x$ (and only $x$) for the inverse function... but I'm not sure if this is flawed or how to actually mathematically show it.

Comment: It's obvious that you can reconstruct $a$ from $M_a$. This gives you the inverse immediately. Alternatively you can show that $\phi$ is injective.

Comment: Thanks, that would be from considering two matrices $M_a = M_b$, and equating components right?

Comment: You are seeing problems where there in fact are none. Your $\phi:\>{\mathbb R}\to G$ is injective by inspection and  surjective by definition. Furthermore you have shown that it is a homomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you meant $\;G=\text{Im}\,\phi\le  GL(3,\Bbb R)\;$ , and to answer your question: you simply have to prove the easy following fact

$$\ker\phi=\{0\}$$

Comment: We havent done much on Linear Algebra yet, so I'm not sure how I could show that.  
Why does this guarantee bijectiveness (and I think we can show that the kernel is empty but just noting the diagonal elements of $M_a$ are never zero right?)

Comment: I supposed you already know that a homomorphism (of groups, of rings, of linear spaces...) is injective iff its kernel is trivial...You could easily prove this elementary fact, and then you'd be done. And the kernel is **never** empty, as it *always* contains at least the unit element of the definition space (group, ring...)

Comment: @Natash1: The kernel are all elements mapped to the neutral element. The neutral element of $G$ is the unit matrix, not the zero matrix.

Comment: Thanks guys. I got mixed up with the neutral element being the identity element of $G$, but the kernel of a linear transformation mapping to the zero vector.